# android program access email account straight through my input IU

Tags: android

If given email id and password in editText, click on login button I need to access my Email account. Is it possible, I need source code for this.plzzz help me.

Comment: Hi! Please read the introduction on how to ask a good question. This will improve your chances of getting an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the email application you are using and trying to open but probably you will not have access to do that programmatically.

However, if you want just to open your email app straight away and send an email it can be done using intents like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, editText_email_id.Text);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "any subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Mail"));
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok sir. This code we are just send mail, but i expect what for if i enter both mail id and password in editText and click button for login i need to get my email(exm: gmai) ACCOUNT , but not on straight url access. Please. Help me sir, i am waiting for this source code.